# How I can repeat a function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I tried using an infinite loop within this function however, when I set up the `setInterval` the function doesn't repeat. The problem is when the user sends the form and after the time interval passes. The function stays on the sent message and doesn't start from the beginning.  Please see my [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/65hyn/last).

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){

  function show_fb() {
    $("#feedback_box").show("slow");    
  }

  function hideAll() {
    $("#feedback_box").hide("slow");
  }

  $("#feedback_box #close").click(function() { // When the X is pressed
    $("#feedback_box").hide("slow"); // Hide the form
  });

  setInterval(show_fb,1000); // Show the form after 6 seconds , you can change 6000 to anything you like    

  $("#feedback_form").submit(function() { //When the form is submitted

    $('#feedback_form #fb_title').css('background-color','#4444FF').text('Sending...').slideDown(900); //show "Sending" message

    $.post("form_submit.php",{ mesaj:$('#mesaj').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data) { //subimit the feedback via AJAX

        $('#feed_subm').attr("disabled", "false"); //disable the "SEND" button
        $('#feedback_form #fb_title').css('background-color','#C33').text('Thank You!').slideDown(900); //Shows a thank you message
        setTimeout(hideAll,2000); // Hide the form after 2 seconds

    });

  });

  return false; //Tells the code not to post the form physically

});
```

**HTML:**

```
</head>
<body>

    <div id="feedback_box"> 
        <form id="feedback_form"> 
            <span id="fb_title">Give us some feedback :)</span><span id="close">X</span> 
            <textarea id="mesaj"></textarea> 
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="mysubm" id="feed_subm"/> 
        </form> 
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please don't post Mediafire links with dubious files. Use jsBin or jsFiddle.

Comment: ok, for the next I'll use JsBin thank for you information.

Comment: @BlueMoonMoonPro You don't have to wait for the next question. Replace the mediafire link in this one with a demonstration.

Comment: here its:  [link](http://jsbin.com/65hyn/last/edit)

Comment: `function repeat() { setTimeout(function() { repeat(); }, 1); } repeat();`

Comment: @Titanium can you give me a example with the script code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat a function in jQuery like this:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // First we will create the function that will be repeated
  function repeat() {

    setTimeout(function() {

      // Enter your code that you want to repeat in here

      repeat(); // This is where the function repeats

    }, 1); // Where 1 is the delay (in milliseconds)

  }

  repeat(); // Here we are initially firing the function

});
```

In your example above, I can't see why you would need a function constantly being repeated however your question was *How I can repeat a function in jQuery?*

Which I think means *How can I repeat a function in jQuery?*

Well here's your answer.

Comment: The problem is you check the script you can see that the fuction seding a message, then the fuction repeat its action but no from the beginning. unless the sending part causing the usaers can resend a message back.